# How to filter _source in reactivesearch?

Tags: reactivesearch

I need to *exclude* certain fields from the `_source` field in the elastic response since those fields are huge and transferring them unnecessarily wastes lots of time. In general, in elastic this is done by providing `_source` parameter in the query, e.g.:

```
GET /_search
{
    "_source": { "excludes": [ "content" ] },
    "query" : { ... }
}
```

Searchkit, for example, does this exclusion for *highlighted* fields automatically (which would be ideal in my case), but also supports an option for user to provide `_source` filter irrespective of highlighting too. Reactivesearch `DataSearch` component seems to be missing this kind of capability.

I can't figure out how to add `_source` (or any other search parameter) to the reactivesearch `DataSearch` query. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We currently don't support this behavior in ReactiveSearch, but we should. I have filed an issue for the same https://github.com/appbaseio/reactivesearch/issues/417.

Edit: This is now supported, you can see how to pass it in the documentation of [Result components](https://opensource.appbase.io/reactive-manual/result-components/reactivelist.html#props).