# Static filters in ReactiveSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, reactivesearch

In my application I'm using the excellent [ReactiveSearch](https://opensource.appbase.io/reactivesearch/).

There are some constants which need to be filtered on every query. For example, to pass a list of ids which would always be filtered and then the user's filtering applied over the top.

There is a [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50880533/how-to-filter-source-in-reactivesearch), but this is focused more on removing fields.

How can a pass an array of IDs to be filtered against a specific field in ElasticSearch? I'm happy to use any kind of hacky approach, such as making a custom component to house the IDs, and then hiding it with CSS, but if there is a cleaner approach please let me know.

Comment: Not sure of reactivesearch but in elasticsearch you can use terms query inside a filter clause to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the ways of solving this is using the prop `defaultQuery` in your result component. For example, `ReactiveList` supports this prop ([docs](https://opensource.appbase.io/reactive-manual/result-components/reactivelist.html#props)). You can use this to run any query of your choice that would get applied along with other queries. For example:

```
<ReactiveList
  ...
  defaultQuery={() => ({
    bool: {
      must_not: {
        term: {
          "original_title.raw": "The Last Guardian"
        }
      }
    }
  })}
/>
```

This would filter out all the `original_title.raw` fields matching `The Last Guardian`. See [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/oo8o3zrlyy).